# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index for Phase Estimation

Tags: python, signal-processing

Write a function to estimate the phase of an image from a symmetric region at the center of k-space. Hint: use the method shown in class, which includes zero-padding and filtering. (see format below. Note: The format below is an example format. You can change it as you wish.)

```
def estimate_phs(k_space,N):
 kx, ky = kdata.shape
 phase = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=kdata.dtype)
 phase_ref = (ky - (N // 2)) * 2
 hamming = window('hamming', (kx, phase_ref))
 phase[:, ky - phase:ky] = kdata[:, ky - phase_ref:ky] * hamming
 estimated_phase = np.angle(ifft2c(x=phase))
 return estimated_phase

phs_estimated = estimate_phs(k_space=kdata,N=N_y)
plt.imshow(abs(phs_estimated),cmap="gray",norm=clr.PowerNorm(gamma=0.3))
plt.title("Estimated Phase")
plt.show()
```

Error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
> index

Comment: probably somewhere in the code (at the line that throws error) you need to convert values to ints, `.astype(np.int32)`

Answer (score -1):

```
def estimate_phs (kdata,N):
    kx, ky = kdata.shape
    phase = np.zeros((kx,N), dtype=kdata.dtype)
    phase_ref = (ky - (N // 2)) * 2
    hamming = window('hamm', (kx, phase_ref))
    phase[:, ky - phase_ref:ky] = kdata[:, ky - phase_ref:ky] * hamming
    estimated_phase = np.angle(ifft2c(x=phase))
    return estimated_phase
phs_estimated = estimate_phs(kdata,N=N_y)
plt.imshow(abs(phs_estimated),cmap="gray")
plt.title("Estimated Phase")
plt.show()
```

This code worked. I changed this line

```
phase = np.zeros((kx,N), dtype=kdata.dtype)
```